# Setup secondary router (ip redirect issue)

Tags: router, modem

the host and the other is to extend it.. I want to use wifi and etnernet cable on my 2nd router also. The problem is when i connect the ethernet cable from host modem to 2nd modem and disable dhcp, the internet doesn't work properly. The router ip configuration settings page keep redirecting to host and its own settings page.. Its like loop when the ip redirects to host network it works well but when it redirect to its own settings page the internet doesn't work and sometimes the rourer freezes like i cant access the settings so i have to reset it everytime..

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is your goal? Are you trying to create two networks for use, or trying to isolate your network from the first router?  I do the latter, as my ISP has unfettered access to the combination modem/router they provide, and I need their MOCA modem/router for the coax to ethernet conversion, but don't want to buy my own because I have a good router already. My second router blocks anyone with access to the first modem/router from accessing my private network. Here are my setup steps:

1. Set up first modem/router to connect per ISP's instructions
2. Attach first LAN port of the first modem/router to the WAN of second router
3. Ensure second router uses a different subnet (e.g. 192.168.44.0) for it's LAN than first modem/router (e.g. 192.168.1.0) uses for it's LAN (and WAN)
4. Ensure remote administration of second router is DISABLED, to keep ISP out of your business
5. Reserve an IP on the first modem/router (e.g. 192.168.1.10)
6. Assign WAN on second router the reserved address (192.168.1.10), with appropriate subnet and DNS
7. Set up second router LAN and WiFi as desired
8. (Optional) Enable WiFi on first modem/router for guests

   - Give second router WiFi access ONLY to household devices and users
   - Guests will not be able to access LAN or private WiFi devices (without setting up port forwarding and routing)
   - Private LAN/WiFi devices should be able to access guest devices by IP
   - Private LAN devices can access guest devices by name ONLY if the second router uses the first modem/router as it's DNS server.

DHCP will work instead of steps 4 & 5, but better to not need to lookup the address.
Given the example IPs, I can access my second (LAN) router at it's IP 192.168.44.1, and the first (WAN) modem/router at it's IP 192.168.1.1.

If you need the first modem/router ONLY for connection to your ISP, you can also set it to pass-through mode instead of the steps above (same wire connections) and your second router will obtain an address from your ISP if you have a dynamic public IP or can be set to your assigned IP(s) if you have static public IPs. Some ISP configurations may require your second router to use a specific MAC address, username, password, or some combination of these. You may lose the ability to access the first modem/router after setting it to pass-through mode, requiring a hard reset to regain it; consult the manual first if this is a concern.

Most routing devices will allow you to save the current configuration, downloading a file to your local machine. You can later upload it to the device to restore that configuraion. I suggest saving the configuration for each device before making any changes and after completing any changes, renaming the files to something very descriptive each time. This is usually much less painful than calling your ISP's tech support to reconfigure your modem/router to a working configuration if you break it.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is when I connect the Ethernet cable from host modem to
> 2nd modem and disable DHCP, the internet doesn't work properly.   ...
> The router IP configuration settings page keep redirecting to host and
> its own settings page.

Make sure you have connected a LAN port (not WAN port) of the 2nd modem (device) to a LAN port on the host modem (device).

While you are doing this, you should give the 2nd device a static IP on the host device network. This is necessary with DHCP OFF as the LAN section needs an IP address of the main device. This also prevents the 2nd device from getting lost if you need to reset the host device.

Of course, DHCP should remain disabled on the 2nd device.

When you have completed the changes, reset both devices and they should connect properly.

If you have any issues, you can always reset the 2nd device to factory defaults and set it up again. Leave the host device as it was until you finish.

Now you can set up Wireless on the 2nd device.

(I think you mean Router when you say Modem).

Good luck with this.

For all viewers:

Here is a screen shot of my Host Device 1. Wired Router with Ethernet Ports. The first device clearly shows the DHCP range for the whole network and that DHCP is enabled.

[image]

Here is a screen shot of my Second Device 2. Wireless router that also has Ethernet ports. The second screen shot clearly shows the LAN settings, the IP on the main device and DHCP disabled.

[image]

Comment: Hey, i have tried this my dhcp is off and internet is working but problem is speed is very slow like 5,10 kbps.. And i am using 2nd ethenet cable for my pc on my 2nd router.. Speed issue is not fixing please tell any solution

Comment: You connected Device 2 to Device 1 with Ethernet (you said), so try an Ethernet port on Device 2 and check the speed. The variation may come from using Wireless on Device 2. Make sure the cable is good. Temporarily move Device 2 near Device 1 and try a different cable.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if both routers have the same IP address assigned on their LAN Interface. Although 192.168.1.1 is common  only 1 device can have a given IP in a LAN, othereise you have the kinds of problems you describe.

If you have connected LAN to LAN (which your post implies but does not state) change the IP address if the router that has DHCP disabled to 192.168.1.253 or some other address in the range which is not in use.